# Correct usage of drake::expose_imports() - Where to place call - Is it recursive?

Tags: r, drake-r-package

## Summary

I've noticed hints/suggestions/warnings in the `drake` docs suggesting use of `expose_imports` to ensure that changes in imported packages are tracked reproducibly, but the docs are relatively brief on the correct usage of this.

## Example

I've now witnessed an example of the behaviour `expose_imports` is designed to correct in my own usage of `drake`, and I'd like to start using it.

In my case, the dependency that wasn't tracked was `forcats`, which, in version `0.4.0` had a bug in `fct_collapse` (Used by one of my functions) which would assign incorrect groups to the output factor.

`0.4.0.9000` resolved this bug, and I updated to `0.4.0.9000`, some time ago, but did notice that targets that must have run against the old version were not invalidated.

## Question

I'm guessing that this is a problem that `expose_imports` might mitigate, but I don't really understand how / where to use it.

If I make scoped calls to `my.package` in my `drake` plans like so:

```r
plan <- drake::drake_plan(
  mtc = mtcars,
  mtc_xformed = my.package::transfom_mtc(mtc)
)
```

And `my.package::transform_mtc()` has some dependency on another package, (Eg. `forcats`) then:

- where should I be calling `expose_imports`?

  - In the `prework` argument of `make`?
  - In the top level of a file in `my.package/R/` ?
- Should I be calling

  - `expose_imports("my.package")` ? or
  - `expose_imports("forcats")`

Some clarification of this would be awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`expose_imports()` is mostly for packages you update/reinstall a lot. For example, say you write a package to implement a new statistical method, and the package is still under active development. Meanwhile, you are also writing a journal article about the method, and you have a reproducible `drake` pipeline to run simulation studies and compile the manuscript. Here, it is important to refresh the paper when you make changes to the package. In the [project archetype here](https://books.ropensci.org/drake/projects.html), your `R/packages.R` file would look something like this:

```r
library(drake)
library(tidyverse)
library(yourCustomPackage)
expose_imports(yourCustomPackage)
```

Then, the plan can use functions from `yourCustomPackage`.

```r
plan <- drake_plan(
   analysis = custom_method(...) # from yourCustomPackages
   # ...
)
```

Now, `drake` will invalidate targets in response to changes in `custom_method()`, along with any nested dependency functions of `custom_method()` in `yourCustomPackages`, and the dependencies of those dependencies in `yourCustomPackages`, etc. (Check `vis_drake_graph()` to see for yourself.)

`expose_imports()` is usually something I only recommend for packages directly related to the content of your research. It is not something I usually recommend for utilities like `forcats`. For those packages, I recommend `renv` to prevent unexpected changes from happening to begin with. In your case, I would update `forcats`, lock it down with `renv`, invalidate the targets you know depend on `forcats`, and trust that future changes to `forcats` are unlikely to be necessary.

Scoped calls like `my.package::transfom_mtc(mtc)` tell `drake` to track `transform_mtc()`, but not any unscoped dependency functions called from `my.package::transfom_mtc(mtc)`. This is a one-foot-in-one-foot-out idea behavior that I no longer agree with. [Next chance I get](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/919), I will make `drake` stop tracking these calls.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.

If I tend to use `drake::r_make()` to run my workflows, where then do these calls to `expose_imports` go? 

> invalidate the targets you know depend on `forcats`

Followup question - How do I invalidate specific targets? 

According to the documents of `drake::clean`, the arguments that allow target selection are both deprecated and shouldn't be used. 

I spent some time searching for an answer to invalid specific targets, and didn't find anything.

Comment: `r_make()` just means you need a `_drake.R` file as I describe at https://books.ropensci.org/drake/projects.html. `expose_imports()` can still go in `R/packages.R` as I recommend above. (You can technically put it anywhere in your pre-`make()` setup, but I recommend putting it next to the `library()` calls to be organized.)

Comment: The `...` and `list` arguments `clean()` are actually not deprecated, that's a mistake in the documentation. I need to fix that. You can still call `clean(your_target_1, your_target_1)` and/or `clean(list = c("target1", "target2"))`.